# Printing out some fields of the objects of a filtered stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Let's suppose there is a Fox class, which has got name, color and age. Let's assume that I have a list of foxes, and I want to print out those foxes' names, whose colours are green. I want to use streams to do so.

Fields:

- name: private String
- color: private String
- age: private Integer

I have written the following code to do the filtering and Sysout:

```
foxes.stream().filter(fox -> fox.getColor().equals("green"))
     .forEach(fox -> System.out::println (fox.getName()));
```

However, there are some syntax issues in my code.

What is the problem? How should I sort it out?

Comment: Either `.forEach(fox -> System.out.println (fox.getName()));` or `.map(Fox::getname).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot combine method references with lambdas, just use one:

```
foxes.stream()
     .filter(fox -> fox.getColor().equals("green"))
     .forEach(fox -> System.out.println(fox.getName()));
```

or the other:

```
foxes.stream()
     .filter(fox -> fox.getColor().equals("green"))
     .map(Fox::getName) // required in order to use method reference in the following terminal operation
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @Csongi Nagy What is a method reference ?  
A way to replace/shortcut the lambda writing. 
So you may use it instead of a lambda, never with a lambda.   
Note also that not every lambdas can be replaced by a method reference. The Aomine example shows how you could make it possible for your requirement.

Answer (score 9):

Simply use :

```
foxes.stream().filter(fox -> fox.getColor().equals("green"))
              .forEach(fox -> System.out.println(fox.getName()));
```

The reason is because you cannot use method references and lambda expressions together.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
foxes.stream().filter(this::isColorGreen).map(Fox::getName).forEach(System.out::println);


public boolean isColorGreen(Fox fox) {
    return fox.getColor().equals("green");
}
```